# PCA fails to run on entire training set of CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

## Goal

I have a CNN which takes in 36x36 images of Graphs and classifies them as either Linear, Quadratic, or Cubic. I want to reduce the training time and eventually train the CNN using higher-resolution images.
[image]

There are 3 classes in the CNN, and 10,000 training images for each class for a total of 30,000 training images. The CNN has a validation accuracy of 99.58%.

## Problem

However, as you can see from the above example, most of the pixels in the training set are useless, white pixels. In fact, the average training image is 78.9% white pixels. That's a lot of wasted computational time spent analyzing useless pixels.

## Attempt #1 (9 Images)

That's why I considered Dimensionality Reduction techniques, specifically the PCA. In my previous question, I inquired how to use PCA on a sample of 9 images. After help from @hafiz031 and some tinkering on my part, I was able to achieve this goal. Below you can see 9 sample training images before and after PCA (7/9 dimensions used; 22% Compression):
[image]

## Attempt #2 (Entire training set: 30,000 Images)

Now that I've seen PCA work on a small scale, I want to ramp up and perform PCA on my entire training set of 30,000 images to see if it reduces the training time for my network (currently at 135 seconds for 3 Epochs & Variable Learning Rate = 0.01).

**However, when I try to run PCA on the entire training set, the following error occurs:**

[image]

Why is this happening? Why am I restricted to only 32 images for some reason? How do I expand my PCA to the entire training set? My full code is [**here**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qSM91iQ-jElizS6_7COY7OWgQGEQPGRT?usp=sharing) and the MWE is below.

```
"""# Import Libraries"""

# Import Libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

"""# Load Dataset"""

import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://barisciencelab.tech/TrainingSet.tar.gz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin = dataset_url,
                                   fname = "TrainingSet",
                                   untar = True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

"""# Display # Images to check"""

print(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
print(image_count)

"""# Display sample image"""

pip install sklearn

import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

graphs = list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png'))
PIL.Image.open(str(graphs[6]))

"""# Define Image Dimensions & Batch Size"""

batch_size = 32
img_height = 36
img_width = 36

"""# Create Training & Validation Sets (80%, 20%)"""

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

"""# Define 3 Classes"""

class_names = ['Cubic Sinusoidal', 'Linear Sinusoidal', 'Quadratic Sinusoidal']
print(class_names)

"""# Supervised Learning (9 Samples from the Training Set)"""

!pip install skimage

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subGraphs = []
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    subGraphs.append(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

subGraphs = np.array(subGraphs)
print(subGraphs.shape)

grayscale = rgb2gray(subGraphs[1])
print(grayscale.shape)

# NEW LINES
grayscale = rgb2gray(subGraphs)
print(grayscale.shape)

grayscale = grayscale.reshape((grayscale.shape[0], grayscale.shape[1] * grayscale.shape[2]))
print(grayscale.shape)

# REVISED LINES
X=grayscale 

pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 3)
X_proj = pca_oliv.fit_transform(X)

print(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.xlabel('# Dimensions')
plt.ylabel('Explained Variance')
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(np.reshape(pca_oliv.components_, (54,72)), cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')

X_inv_proj = pca_oliv.inverse_transform(X_proj)
print(X_inv_proj.shape)
for index in range(len(X_inv_proj)): # 9                    
  X_proj_img = np.reshape(X_inv_proj[index],(36,36))
  plt.imshow(X_proj_img, cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')
  plt.title(class_names[labels[index]])
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.show()

for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break

"""# Normalize Inputs (/255px)"""

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

"""# Architechture of CNN (3 Conv2Ds, 3 MaxPool2Ds, 2 Dense and Flatten)"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# Load the TensorBoard notebook extension
# %load_ext tensorboard

import tensorflow as tf
import datetime

# Clear any logs from previous runs
!rm -rf ./logs/

num_classes = 3

# IDENTIFY PARAMETERS FOR Conv2D(A,B, )
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), #32 FILTERS and square stride of size 3
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam', 
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

epochs = 3

initial_learning_rate = 0.01
decay = initial_learning_rate / epochs

def lr_time_based_decay(epoch, lr):
    return lr * 1 / (1 + decay * epoch)

history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs= epochs,
  callbacks= [tensorboard_callback, tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_time_based_decay, verbose=1)]
)

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# %tensorboard --logdir logs/fit

model.summary()

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Train & Val. Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Train & Val. Loss')
plt.show()

"""# Image Input Array"""

pip install glob2

preds = []

for i in range(0,999):

  lin_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Refath/SinusoidalAnalyzer/main/Validation/Graph_"+str(i)+".png"
  lin_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Graph_'+str(i)+'.png', origin=lin_url)

  img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
      lin_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
  )

  img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

  predictions = model.predict(img_array)
  score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

  print(
      "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
      .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
  )
  preds.append(np.argmax(score))

print(preds)
results = []

for i in range(0,len(preds)):
  results.append(0)

for i in range(0, len(preds)):
  if preds[i] == 0:
    results[i] = "Cubic"
  elif preds[i] == 1:
    results[i] = "Linear"
  else: 
    results[i] = "Quadratic"

print(results)

len(preds)

"""# Confusion Matrix"""

actual = [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1]
tf.math.confusion_matrix(preds, actual)

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

y_true = actual
y_pred = preds
data = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Cubic','Linear','Quadratic'], index = ['Cubic','Linear','Quadratic'])
df_cm.index.name = 'Actual'
df_cm.columns.name = 'Predicted'
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.set(font_scale=1.4)
sn.heatmap(df_cm, cmap="Blues", annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16}, fmt='g')
```

Comment: You take 1 batch from your `train_ds`, which you define with `batch_size = 32`

Comment: Wait, so I have to increase my `batch_size` from 32 to 30,000? Then won't I have only one batch for the entire epoch?

Comment: @dm2 I just changed it to `batch_size=30,000` and it says `InvalidArgumentError: slice index 24000 of dimension 0 out of bounds. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/`

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure about the best way to go about doing what you're trying to do (I doubt increasing batch_size to include all images is a good way about doing that), just pointed out where your issue was (otherwise I would have posted an answer and not a comment). That being said, you have 30 000 total images, and your train_ds is 80% of that. That works out to be 24 000.